# Setting corner radius of an element in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My code is almost working, but there is one issue.

As soon as the table is loaded, images looks are as follows:

[image: As soon as the table is loaded, images looks are as follows]

But when i scroll the table everything is good:

[image: But when i scroll the table everything is good]

What is missing here?

```
class ShopTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

@IBOutlet weak var shopImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imagesCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var imageContainer: UIView!

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    imageContainer.clipsToBounds = true
    imageContainer.layer.cornerRadius = imageContainer.frame.size.width / 2
    imageContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1
    imageContainer.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hex: "#BDBDBD").CGColor
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the frame property of your imageview is not updated yet.

You can make a subclass of UIImageView and do that job there,
like:

Swift

```
class CircleImageView: UIImageView {

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.layer.borderWidth = 1 / UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hex: "#BDBDBD").CGColor
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width/2
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
  }
}
```

Objective-C

```
@implementation CircleImageView

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.layer.borderWidth = 1 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width/2;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

@end
```